# Correct method for an app store submission

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am just about ready to submit my app to the store and would like to know any tips or best practices from fellow iphone developers who  have submitted to the store before.

What needs to be done before submission?

How is the binary created or packaged?( what things should be kept in mind)

What is the idea behind scheduling a release date? (can it not just be released after it has been accepted)

What else needs to be done in order to submit?

Any bad experiences which developers could take note of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, have you gone through Apples docs on submission: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/appstore/submission.html

In general, the process is to log into itunesconnect.apple.com using your iPhone developer account, click "manage applications", then "Add new application" and fill in the forms.

You need to build a distribution version of your app codesigned with an iPhone Distribution cert.  The Distribution cert can be obtained from the iPhone Developer Portal (http://developer.apple.com/iphone click "iPhone Provisioning Portal" on the right.)  When you have a distribution build, you just need to zip up the app.  Open the MyAppProject/build/Release-iphoneos directory in Finder, right-click on myApp.app and select "Compress 'myApp.app'" from the context menu.  For very large apps, you will need the Application Loader available from the App Management section of iTunesConnect to upload the binary.

In general, it takes at least a week for an app to be processed by Apple.  Typically, as soon as Apple accepts the app, it's available for sale.  That said, if you don't tell anyone about the app, no one will find it.

For me, the hardest parts of the app submission process are writing the blurb and coming up with the list of keywords.

Answer (score 2):

How is the binary created or packaged?

Goto
build/distribution-iphoneos/ inside that you have .app file compress it and that compressed file is to be uploaded.

upload should be done through APPLICATION LOADER.

Answer (score 1):

These are the following steps needed to build an iPhone app under an Apple Distribution License and upload it to the App Store.

1. Create A **CSR** from **Keychain Access** in a Mac machine. 
   Access Keychain Access as  Finder>>Applications>>Utilities>>Keychain Access.
       Upload this CSR while creating a Distribution Certificate.
   **An Apple License can have only one Apple Distribution Certificate.**
2. Download Distribution Certificate.
   Open Keychain Access.
   Access Keychain Access as  Finder>>Applications>>Utilities>>Keychain Access.
   Install the downloaded Distribution Certificate.
   Right Click on the Distribution Certificate and select **"Export Certificate"** and  save as Personal Interchange Certificate (.p12) format in destination Library>>Keychains.
3. For every **new application** we need to create **new Provisioning Profiles** under **one Apple Distribution Certificate.**
   For each **new Provisioning Profile**, we need to create a **new App Id.**
   So we need to create a  Adhoc and Appstore Provisioning Profile.
4. **Adhoc** Provisioning Profile is for **testing the app in apple devices.**
   **Appstore** Provisioining Profile is for **uploading the app to appstore.**
   Download the respective Provisioning Profile and double click on the profile to install it. 
   Delete all the previous profiles and just **retain the newly installed profile.**
5. Build the application by selecting the Code Signing Entity as the newly installed Provisioning Profile.

6   Upload the **ApplicationName.app.zip** file as the binary file in **Application loader** while uploading the application to appstore.

Reference: **https://developer.apple.com**

I believe this would be of some help to you.